# If a sequence in metric space $(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with euclidean norm is Cauchy, then is it element-wise cauchy?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

So let's say I have metric space $(\mathbb{R}^n, d)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $n$ is infinity. We also have
$$d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n|x_i - y_i|^2}$$ which is essentially the Euclidean norm.

Now let's introduce a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is Cauchy. Is it also element-wise Cauchy?

Also if $(x_n)$ is convergent, then is it also element-wise convergent?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself? How far did you get?

Comment: As $\mathbb R^n$ is a finite-dimensional space, all norms are equivalent. In particular equivalent to the $\sup$ norm... Or more directly $\lvert x_i - y_i \rvert \le d(x,y)$ for $1 \le i \le n$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net could you further elaborate on what you mean by "all norms are equivalent"?

Comment: I suggest that you have a look at [equivalent norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalent_norms).

Comment: I think the phrase you intend is "component-wise", not "element-wise", but I'm not sure, so i haven't edited your question. But please fix it if that is what you mean.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC in your case I meant "component-wise".

Comment: Notation "a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$" is confusing, since it uses $n$ for two different things.  Unless you really do mean $x_1 \in \mathbb R^1, x_2 \in \mathbb R^2,x_3 \in \mathbb R^3$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $i \in \{1, \dots, n \}$, we have

$$\lvert x_i - y_i \rvert \le d(x,y).$$ From there, you can easily prove that if $\{x_n\}$ converges to $l=(l_1, \dots, l_n)$, then the $i$-th coordinate of $\{x_n\}$ converges to $l_i$. And a similar things for Cauchy sequences.